# Load variables into LESS CSS preprocessor from JSON file

Tags: javascript, css, json, less, stylus

Is it possible to load variables into LESS CSS preprocessor from a JSON file like you can do with Stylus?

With contents of file `myvars.json`

```
{
    "color1": "#112345",
    "color2": "#667890"
}
```

In Stylus I do...

```
json('myvars.json')
body{ background-color: color1; }
```

Is it possible to do this in LESS?

I want to keep the file as JSON, so I can easily re-use it in javascript.

Answer (score 20):

In **less.js** you can make use of javascript interpolation (using the back-ticks). And call a function that loads the json object with the variables from the file ... from which you can extract the variable by its key - something in this direction perhaps:

```
@json_file: myvars.json;

@json: ~`json = function($key) { var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); request.open("GET", "@{json_file}", false); request.send(null); var my_json = JSON.parse(request.responseText); return my_json[$key]; }`;

body {
  background-color: ~`json('color1')`;
}
```

this might not look super elegant, but it works. A more elegant option would probably be to define your custom user function in the [global LESS object before calling the script](http://lesscss.org/#usage), but I never really bothered playing with that, as I was always using LESS client-side just in development.

Another thing that you can do - is loading the json file in javascript (after calling the LESS script in the browser) and using the `less.modifyVars()` function to recompile LESS with the json variables. You can do something along this lines in your html (here I use plain JS but it's even simpler if you use jQuery.getJSON):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">less = { env: "development" };</script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.4.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "myvars.json", false);
    request.send(null);
    var my_json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    less.modifyVars(my_json);
</script>
```

and something like this in your LESS style file:

```
@color1: darkblue; //default value - will get overwritten by .modifyVars()

body {
  background-color: @color1;
}
```

**Another note:** all variable names in LESS have to begin with an *at* sign (`@`). However, the json variables do not need to, because `less.modifyVars()` automatically prepends the variables with an `@` if missing.

Hope this gives you some ideas. There might be better ways to do it ... but this two approaches worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you not use LESS in browser but compile the CSS, I just publish a gulp plugin to do this job.

It can look like this :

`css/myvars.json`

```
{
    "color1": "#112345",
    "color2": "#667890"
}
```

`less/styles.less`

```
@json-import "myvars.json";

body {
  background-color: @color1;
}
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var lessJsonImport = require('gulp-less-json-import');

gulp.task('less', function(){ 
  gulp.src(['./less/**/*.less', '!./less/**/_*.less'])
      .pipe(lessJsonImport())
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using LESS in browser, there is also 'globalVars' option that can be used to set variables before loading the LESS files: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globalVars` less option to provide object loaded from json file.

For example with less-loader plugin `webpack.config.js` will be like:

```
function lessGlobalVars() {
    return require('flat')(require('./path/to/config.json'),
        {
            delimiter: '_'
        });
}

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              globalVars: lessGlobalVars()
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

`config.json`:

```
{
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 100,
    "height": 50
  }
}
```

`globalVars` accepts only flat structures so we need [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package that will flatten object loaded with `require('./path/to/config.json')` to:

```
{
  dimensions_width: 100,
  dimensions_height: 50
}
```

Passing this object to `globalVars` option will make global variable `@dimensions_width` and `@dimensions_height` available for all your less stylesheets:

```
.some-class {
  width: @dimensions_width;
  height: @dimensions_height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively new approach is described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-loader):

`myPluginFile.js`:

```
const axios = require('axios').default

module.exports = {
  install: function (less, pluginManager, functions) {
    functions.add("blue", function () {

      const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        timestamp: +new Date(),
      }  
      
      try {
        const method = 'get'
        const url = 'https://myAPI.com/myFile.json'
        const options = { headers: { ...headers } }
        const { data } = await axios[method](url, {}, options)
        return data
      } catch (error) {
        console.info('Error', { msg: error.message })
      }
    });
  },
};
```

`myStyleFile.less`:

```
@plugin "myPluginFile";

/* Style the body */
body {
  color: blue();
}
```